# Transformar un json en otro con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un json devuelto con la API de Google Vision que es el resultado de la subida de 3 imágenes distintas, pero en una misma subida...

```
    [
  {
    "errorMessage": "",
    "errorStatus": false,
    "fileMimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "fileName": "19091_047031795420170519212400126191-1-3.jpg",
    "meanConfidence": 100,
    "milliSecondsEmployed": 206650,
    "ocrInUse": true,
    "pageCount": 1,
    "pageDataList": [
      {
        "height": 2631,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "rawText": "texto completo",
        "textSegments": [
          {
            "geometry": {
                "x": 1694.25,
                "y": -57
            },
            "orientation": 0,
            "text": "texto"
          }
        ],
        "width": 1860
      }
    ],
    "pending": false
  },
  {
    "errorMessage": "",
    "errorStatus": false,
    "fileMimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "fileName": "19091_047031795420170519212400126191-1-3.jpg",
    "meanConfidence": 100,
    "milliSecondsEmployed": 206654,
    "ocrInUse": true,
    "pageCount": 1,
    "pageDataList": [
      {
        "height": 2631,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "rawText": "texto completo",
        "textSegments": [
          {
            "geometry": {
                "x": 594.75,
                "y": -134.25
            },
            "orientation": 0,
            "text": "texto"
          }
        ],
        "width": 1860
      }
    ],
    "pending": false
  },
  {
    "errorMessage": "",
    "errorStatus": false,
    "fileMimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "fileName": "19091_047031795420170519212400126191-1-2.jpg",
    "meanConfidence": 100,
    "milliSecondsEmployed": 238255,
    "ocrInUse": true,
    "pageCount": 1,
    "pageDataList": [
      {
        "height": 2631,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "rawText": "texto completo",
        "textSegments": [
          {
            "geometry": {
                "x": 101.25,
                "y": -69.75
            },
            "orientation": 0,
            "text": "texto"
          }
        ],
        "width": 1860
      }
    ],
    "pending": false
  }
]
```

He acortado mucho su formato para este ejemplo... lo que quiero es que las páginas se vayan agregando a un nuevo json, de lan forma que queden agrupadas como en este otro json:

```
    [
  {
    "errorMessage": "",
    "errorStatus": false,
    "fileMimeType": "application/pdf",
    "fileName": "19091_047031795420170519212400126191-1.pdf",
    "meanConfidence": 100,
    "milliSecondsEmployed": 4750,
    "ocrInUse": false,
    "pageCount": 2,
    "pageDataList": [
      {
        "height": 841.8898,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "rawText": "texto completo",
        "textSegments": [
          {
            "geometry": {
                "x": 368.24878,
                "y": -58.73446
            },
            "orientation": 0,
            "text": "texto"
          }]
      },
      {
        "height": 841.8898,
        "pageNumber": 2,
        "rawText": "texto completo",
        "textSegments": [
          {
            "geometry": {
                "x": 47.452,
                "y": -73.23697
            },
            "orientation": 0,
            "text": "texto"
          }]
      }
    ],
    "pending": false
  }
]
```

Es decir, que todas las páginas vayan dentro de pageDataList, no que se cree uno distinto por cada página. ¿Cómo puedo cambiar de un tipo de json al otro?

Comment: Hola Norak, agrega el código que has hecho hasta el momento y en que parte estas teniendo el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una función que tome los valores almacenados en la propiedad pageDataList a partir del segundo elemento de tu arreglo y lo vaya anexando a la misma propiedad pero del primer elemento, de manera que esos valores esten solo en esa propiedad en el primer elemento y puedas deshacerte de los demás sin perder esos datos. Te propongo probar lo siguiente, a mi me funciona pero debes verificar que resuelva tu problema puntual.

```
//Creo una función para reformar mi JSON
var normalizar = function(obj){
  //Recorro el arreglo del JSON desde la segunda posición ya que tomare sus valores para ponerlos en el primer elemento
  for(var i=1;i<obj.length;i++){
    //Si tiene la propiedad "pageDataList"
    if(obj[i].pageDataList !== undefined){
      //Añado el dato almacenado en pageDataList a la propiedad con el mismo nombre del primer elemento
      obj[0].pageDataList.push(obj[i].pageDataList);
      //Elimino la propiedad en el elemento actual de la iteración
      delete obj[i].pageDataList;
    }
  }
  //Elimino los elementos del arreglo excepto el primero ya que su informacion ya se pasó hacia el arreglo de la propiedad
  //"pageDataList"
  for(var j=1;j<obj.length;j++){
    delete obj[j];
  }
};

//Dejo los datos con la estructura nueva
normalizar(data);

//Muestro la nueva estructura
console.log(data);
```

Aclaro que usé el mismo JSON que incluistes en tu pregunta

Comment: Hola Dariel. Gracias por aportar. sin embargo deberias esperar a que el autor muestre su codigo ya que sobre el podemos ayudarle en vez de darle un metodo totalmente nuevo y distinto al que el ya estaba usando . Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Tomando como referencia la información que nos proporcionas quiero asumir que te responde esa información en una cadena de texto la cual se tendrá que manipular como un objeto json para practicidad.

Esto de manera práctica lo podemos resolver con esto:

```
JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Digamos que tenemos la respuesta en una variable llamada payload. Para obtener el Json que tu requieres tenemos que crear un nuevo objeto del cual supongo va a ser un objeto para generar un pdf. Por lo tanto propongo la siguiente solución utilizando [lodash](https://lodash.com), la cual es una librería bastante recomendable para gestionar estos detalles:

```
var payload = [
    {
        "errorMessage": "",
        "errorStatus": false,
        "fileMimeType": "image/jpeg",
        "fileName": "19091_047031795420170519212400126191-1-3.jpg",
        "meanConfidence": 100,
        "milliSecondsEmployed": 206650,
        "ocrInUse": true,
        "pageCount": 1,
        "pageDataList": [
            {
                "height": 2631,
                "pageNumber": 1,
                "rawText": "texto completo",
                "textSegments": [
                    {
                        "geometry": {
                                "x": 1694.25,
                                "y": -57
                        },
                        "orientation": 0,
                        "text": "texto"
                    }
                ],
                "width": 1860
            }
        ],
        "pending": false
    },
    {
        "errorMessage": "",
        "errorStatus": false,
        "fileMimeType": "image/jpeg",
        "fileName": "19091_047031795420170519212400126191-1-3.jpg",
        "meanConfidence": 100,
        "milliSecondsEmployed": 206654,
        "ocrInUse": true,
        "pageCount": 1,
        "pageDataList": [
            {
                "height": 2631,
                "pageNumber": 1,
                "rawText": "texto completo",
                "textSegments": [
                    {
                        "geometry": {
                                "x": 594.75,
                                "y": -134.25
                        },
                        "orientation": 0,
                        "text": "texto"
                    }
                ],
                "width": 1860
            }
        ],
        "pending": false
    },
    {
        "errorMessage": "",
        "errorStatus": false,
        "fileMimeType": "image/jpeg",
        "fileName": "19091_047031795420170519212400126191-1-2.jpg",
        "meanConfidence": 100,
        "milliSecondsEmployed": 238255,
        "ocrInUse": true,
        "pageCount": 1,
        "pageDataList": [
            {
                "height": 2631,
                "pageNumber": 1,
                "rawText": "texto completo",
                "textSegments": [
                    {
                        "geometry": {
                                "x": 101.25,
                                "y": -69.75
                        },
                        "orientation": 0,
                        "text": "texto"
                    }
                ],
                "width": 1860
            }
        ],
        "pending": false
    }
];
```

Ahora para crear el objeto pdf de manera conveniente creamos un objeto en javascript y para generar su json simplemente ocupamos las bondades de javascript.

```
var pdf = {
    "errorMessage": "",
    "errorStatus": false,
    "fileMimeType": "application/pdf",
    "fileName": "19091_047031795420170519212400126191-1.pdf",
    "meanConfidence": 100,
    "milliSecondsEmployed": 4750,
    "ocrInUse": false,
    "pageCount": 2,
    "pageDataList": _.chain(payload)
    .map(function(image) {
        pageDataList = _.get(image, 'pageDataList');
        if(! _.isUndefined(pageDataList)) {
            return _.first(pageDataList);
        }
    })
    .value(),
};

JSON.stringify(pdf);
```